# Fragment is not attached to a context

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, fragment

I intend to show a list of farms (Fazendas) previously registered in the database (SQLite) in a Fragment called "FazendaListFragment" that is part of the FazendaActivity. Here I have two screens using ViewPage for screen change via sliding, but I have the problem reported in the Title of this questions. I don't know how I solve this problem with attach contexts. Bellow the code:

FazendaActivity

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fazenda)

    setupTabs()
}

private fun setupTabs(){
    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    adapter.addFragment(FazendaListFragment(), "")
    adapter.addFragment(ListaPastoFragment(), "")

    view_pager_fazenda.adapter = adapter
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(view_pager_fazenda)

    tabs.getTabAt(0)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_foundation_24)
    tabs.getTabAt(1)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_outline_fence_24)
}
```

FazendaListFragment **(UPDATED)**

```
ar nameList = ArrayList<String>()

//Iniciando RecyclerView
var fazendaAdapter: FazendaListAdapter? = null
var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager? = null

//Iniciando o SQLite
var fazendaList = ArrayList<Fazenda>()
val fazendaDatabaseHandler by lazy { FazendaDatabaseHandler(requireContext()) }

private var cadastroFazenda: FloatingActionButton? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista_fazenda, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    initView()
}

private fun deleteAdapter(position: Int){
    fazendaList.removeAt(position)
    fazendaAdapter!!.notifyItemRemoved(position)
}

private fun initView() {
    fazendaList = fazendaDatabaseHandler.fazendas()
    fazendaAdapter = FazendaListAdapter(fazendaList, requireContext(), this::deleteAdapter)
    linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerview.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
    recyclerview.adapter = fazendaAdapter
}
```

FazendaListAdapter

```
internal var fazendaList: List<Fazenda> = ArrayList<Fazenda>()
init{
    this.fazendaList = fazendaList
}

//Aqui é onde o ViewHolder é criado a partir do layout
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.content_fazenda_list, parent, true)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

//Nessa parte é onde se modifica o item do ViewHolder
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val fazenda = fazendaList[position]

    holder.name.text = fazenda.nome
    holder.cnpj.text = fazenda.cnpj
    holder.endereco.text = fazenda.endereco

    holder.editbtn.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(context, CadastroFazendaActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("edit", true)
        intent.putExtra("position", fazenda.id)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
    holder.delbtn.setOnClickListener{
        val view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.dialog_confirm_delete_fazenda, null)

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        builder.setView(view)

        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
        dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)

        view.btn_delete.setOnClickListener {
            val fazendaDatabaseHandler = FazendaDatabaseHandler(context)
            fazendaDatabaseHandler.deleteFazenda(fazenda.id)
            callbacks(position)
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
}

//Devolve a quantidade de itens do fazendaList
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return fazendaList.size
}

//Aqui é a criação dos itens do ViewHolder
inner class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    var name: TextView = view.tvAdpNome
    var cnpj: TextView = view.tvAdpCNPJ
    var endereco: TextView = view.tvAdpEndereco
    var delbtn: Button = view.deleteButton
    var editbtn: Button = view.editButton
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter

```
private val mFragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
private val mFragmentTitleList = ArrayList<String>()

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return mFragmentList[position]
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return mFragmentList.size
}

override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    return mFragmentTitleList[position]
}

fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String){
    mFragmentList.add(fragment)
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
}
```

The Log of the error is here:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: br.com.appintellipec, PID: 6685
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.appintellipec/br.com.appintellipec.FazendaActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FazendaListFragment{524ae27} (f65a2c7c-2524-45f7-908a-12db24890acc) not attached to a context.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FazendaListFragment{524ae27} (f65a2c7c-2524-45f7-908a-12db24890acc) not attached to a context.
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:900)
    at br.com.appintellipec.fragments.FazendaListFragment.<init>(FazendaListFragment.kt:32)
    at br.com.appintellipec.FazendaActivity.setupTabs(FazendaActivity.kt:22)
    at br.com.appintellipec.FazendaActivity.onCreate(FazendaActivity.kt:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: is the app not even compiling or is it a runtime error, what exactly is your issue add some `Logs` to help us understand better

Comment: i added the log. is a fatal exception. when it arrives in this fragment it crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call `requireContext()` at a property initialization site because properties are initialized while the Fragment instance is still being constructed, which is before it can possibly be attached to a context. This line has your error:

```
var fazendaDatabaseHandler = FazendaDatabaseHandler(requireContext())
```

You can either load it lazily, so it only will call `requireContext()` when you first use the property:

```
val fazendaDatabaseHandler by lazy { FazendaDatabaseHandler(requireContext()) }
```

Or you can make it `lateinit var` and initialize it in `onViewCreated()`, when it will be safe to call `requireContext()`:

```
lateinit var fazendaDatabaseHandler: FazendaDatabaseHandler

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    fazendaDatabaseHandler = FazendaDatabaseHandler(requireContext())
    //...
}
```

Comment: thank you for it. apparently this problem was solved. but now we have this log:

    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference

Comment: There's not enough code shared to see exactly what's wrong. I don't see your `recyclerView` property declaration. It doesn't make sense that you're calling `initView()` *after* `return` in your `onCreateView()` function or to be redundantly calling it in `onResume()`. Any view setup should be done in `onViewCreated()`.

Comment: If you're using synthetic view references, that has been deprecated because it causes NullPointerExceptions unless you know exactly what you're doing with view initialization, setup, and the Fragment lifecycle. You should migrate to view binding.

Comment: i've updated the FazendaListFragment code in the question. i use "import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_fazendas_list.*" for get this recyclerview directly of the layout.

Comment: I suggest you read these articles and migrate to view binding. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/the-future-of-kotlin-android-extensions.html https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

Comment: in place of recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize once only for the method `initView()`. It is either `onCreateView` or `onResume`.

Next, you should use `requiredContext()` instead `context`.

```
fazendaAdapter = FazendaListAdapter(fazendaList, requiredContext(), this::deleteAdapter)
```

UPDATE:

Looks like you don't implement for the view. All the views should return inside the `onCreateView`. Looks like you return it early.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista_fazenda, container, false)
    initView()
    return view //This one need at the last
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    //initView() //comment this one. you just need to implement one only
}
```

Comment: i did this and i had the same error. i added the log in the question.

Comment: Where did you initialize `view_pager_fazenda` ? @EdgarJr13

Comment: i use "import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_fazendas_list.*" for get this view pager directly of the layout.

Comment: fatal error again. here the log:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.appintellipec/br.com.appintellipec.FazendaActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FazendaListFragment{524ae27} (2d05fa03-9307-423e-9a4d-616ecf00e3bf) not attached to a context.

Comment: explaining more: before this fragment, i have a Activity with 3 viewpagers fragments, with a some cards, that are the options that the user can choose.  they work like a buttons . when I click in a determinate card, the app reigns for this fragment and crash 
without even opening this fragment